# Google maps android api autocomplete

Tags: android, google-places-api

I was following this example to implement autocomplete functionality from google for my Android application. https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

But from JSON response I get the following:

```
02-07 12:53:31.202: D/JSON String(6815): {
02-07 12:53:31.202: D/JSON String(6815):    "predictions" : [],
02-07 12:53:31.202: D/JSON String(6815):    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
02-07 12:53:31.202: D/JSON String(6815): }
```

I know that my `API_KEY` is right, because in the same activity I have implemented google map which works fine. Any ideas what's wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

You need to use `Key for browser apps (with referers)` from APIs console and not the one for Android apps!

Comment: have you added the places api to your project in the google developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Places API you need to use Key for browser apps from APIs console even if you are implementing this functionality in Android application!

Comment: but what would be a REFERERS url ?